# how can i make a duplicate of a rect in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

hi i am trying to make a agent based ant simulation in pygame but i dont know how to make multiple rects and still have it read the food for collision. any ideas? also just a little note i made it go all possible directions but i commented it out for debuging movment for the time being.

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
import random
from pygame.locals import *


pg.init()
pg.display.set_caption("Agent based ant simulation")
clock = pg.time.Clock()

win = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
surf2 = pg.Surface([5, 5])
surf2.fill((255, 255, 255))

ant1 = surf2.get_rect(topleft=[5, 5])

ant1.right = 400
ant1.top = 300

food = pg.Surface([7, 7])
food.fill((0, 255, 0))
food_rect = food.get_rect(topleft=[7, 7])
food_rect.right = random.randint(0, 700)
food_rect.top = random.randint(0, 500)

#Vec2X = random.randint(-5, 5)
#Vec2Y = random.randint(-5, 5)

vel = 5

while True:
   for event in pg.event.get():
       if event.type == pg.QUIT:
           pg.quit()
           sys.exit()

   for i in range(9):
       pg.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0,), (random.randint(0, 700), random.randint(0, 500), 7, 7))

   win.fill((0, 0, 0))
   win.blit(food, food_rect)
   win.blit(surf2, ant1)
#    ant1.right += Vec2X
#    ant1.top += Vec2Y

   userInput = pg.key.get_pressed()
   if userInput[pg.K_a]:
       ant1.x -= vel
   if userInput[pg.K_d]:
       ant1.x += vel
   if userInput[pg.K_w]:
       ant1.y -= vel
   if userInput[pg.K_s]:
       ant1.y += vel

   if ant1.colliderect(food_rect):
       food.fill((0, 0, 0))

       #    if Vec2X == 0 and Vec2Y == 0:
       #        Vec2X = random.randint(-5, 5)
       #        Vec2Y = random.randint(-5, 5)

   pg.display.flip()
   clock.tick(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do collision here?

```
if ant1.colliderect(food_rect):
       food.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

You can do list of foods, like this

```
foods = [foodrect1, foodrect2]
```

And then do

```
for food in foods:
      if ant1.colliderect(food):
           food.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: yes because in the simulation that i watched he had his ants look for food then find some pick it up and bring it back so yes, i do want collision. also for the array do i create them as a rect or what do i do for the foods array?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: not yet look back at the edit i made

Comment: create as a rect